# How can I record an app in background

Tags: safari, google-chrome, recording, screen-recording, soundflower

Due to my poor organization I have 2 simultaneous lectures this semester, at this moment I'm following one on Phone and I record the other one with the Mac (Quicktime and Soundflower)

Is it possible to record Chrome or Safari in the background while doing other things on the screen?

And for my specifical purpose, is it possible to direct the audio of an app on the headphones and the audio of another app to a different output (external speaker or Soundflower to record)?

Comment: Try a [screen recorder browser plugin](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/screenshot-capture-annotate/?utm_source=addons.mozilla.org&utm_medium=referral&utm_content=search) (Firefox, I don’t use Chrome).  Also ask for the stream URL and use FFMPEG or similar tool

Answer (score 0):

It is not immediately possible to record the windows of Chrome/Safari when they're not displayed on screen, as they really aren't rendered when not needed.

You could possibly make a more involved setup by running a virtualized operating system with Chrome that you can record indepedently on whether it is shown on the monitor or not.

Similarly you could do something like running Chrome under X11 using *x11vnc* or similar to enable off-screen recording.

There is also the possibility of using Headless Chrome by way of for example the [puppeteer-video-recorder](https://www.npmjs.com/package/puppeteer-video-recorder) plugin to record a video - however I think it would be quite a hassle to get setup.

As for routing the audio as you wish, you should be able to relatively easily set this up by using the [Loopback](https://rogueamoeba.com/loopback/) program.

Comment: This is a complex solution for recording, does Chrome need to be headless? can't it be open but with other app over? , i tought OBS could do it

Comment: Loopback instead seems perfect for my purpose

Comment: No, Chrome does not need to be headless - I described two solutions where it does not need to be headless. I don't think OSB can handle this out of the box - but OSB is progressing rapidly so it might be possible now (?) Haven't heard of it yet.

Comment: I've tried a VM (Parallels) and a recorder, it's heavy and problematic for the lack of gpu and cpu, loopback cost too much, it's crazy that something so simple have to be so complicated to solve

Comment: Well, it might seem crazy if you do not have insight how modern computers works - but actually it is not a simple problem, it is a very complex problem, you want to solve. That would be the case on any operating system - Windows, Linux or macOS. Regarding Loopback: I'm sure free software exists that will solve your problem - for me the price of Loopback is worth it when I factor in the cost of my time.